# Jenkins - Is it necessary to have a repository for running a multi configuration project

Tags: jenkins

I am new to Jenkins. I am trying to configure Jenkins to run my Selenium tests on multiple browsers. So I thought multi-configuration project would be a best choice. I am using Sauce labs for performing cross-browser testing.

My selenium source code is on my local system directory. I have not uploaded the same to any of the repositories. I have configured a multi-configuration project with a custom workspace pointing to my local source code, and selected "none" in Source code management section.

Now, when I build the job, the job creates workspace for each browser combination. Eg: `<project workspace>\SELENIUM_DRIVER\Windows 2003firefox16` and `<project workspace>\SELENIUM_DRIVER\Windows 2003internet explorer8`. But the files are not copied to each of these workspaces automatically. I need to copy my files manually into these directories for it to work.

Is it necessary to have Repositories like SVN, CVS or Git for this to work. Or is there a way I can run the build from my local system?

Comment: You can build from your local system using a repository like Mercurial or Git.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, a Repository is not required,
but you do need to have some good way to access your *artifacts* and *selenium code*.

Suggest you drop the *artifacts* on a shared drive as a preliminary step,
and also put your *selenium source-code* on a shared drive, as a practice -
this will allow you to run multiple tests from multiple machines.

Cheers